# HTML aside how to hide during for media print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to print a page with an `<aside>`.  I'm also using Bootstrap 3.
I've added `hidden-print` to the `aside` like this:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar hidden-print">
```

However, when I print with Chrome, the space used by the aside is still shown?
How do I make it "disappear" and the rest of the content stretch to fill all the available space when printing?

I'm using the AdminLTE template, you can see a demo here:

https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Notice that if you expand the side bar (the default when opening the page) and do a print preview, the side bar content isn't shown, but their is a blank area.  I want to make the body content fill the entire printed page.

Also, interestingly enough IE11 and FF appear correctly, it is just Chrome that is failing.

Comment: Is the aside in a bootstrap column (this would still be shows as an empty column)? Please show more of your markup.

Comment: @Tims, I added information about the markup I am using, any suggestions are welcome :-)